# онлайн средства для получения данных из макета

Tags: html, вёрстка, инструменты-разработчика

У Adobe есть\был некий продукт, позволяющий заливать макет PSD, и после обработки получать из него всю необходимую информацию в виде цветов\шрифтов  и возможности скачивания отдельных слоёв(картинки и прочее).

Есть ли аналоги и стоит ли пользоваться подобным?На мой взгляд, это самый удобный способ нарезать макет перед версткой. Или я что-то не понимаю?

Comment: Avocode, например. Получше Adobe